# PHP - Change default CSV sheet name

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am creating a CSV file using PHP, but I have to change "Sheet1" name to "Import To Web".  Here is my code:

```
// open the file "demosaved.csv" for writing
$file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'w');

// save the column headers
fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));

// Sample data. This can be fetched from mysql too
$data = array(
    array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
    array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
    array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
    array('Data 41', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
    array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55')
);

// save each row of the data
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}

// Close the file
fclose($file);
```

I try to create CSV but it sets default sheet name to "Sheet1".

Please tell me how to change sheet name.

Comment: This fundamentally bad code -> No error checking. You think your `fopen()` or `fputcsv()` is bullet proof? Wanna bet?

Comment: what should be?

Comment: checking for errors? see docs how what you got returned. and never ignore such things like error handling. that's gonna hit you hard otherwise

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for isn't possible and is fundamentally a misunderstanding of the technology you're using. *Sheet1* is the default name given to a sheet in Excel and has nothing to do with the CSV format.

In Excel, you can have multiple *Sheets* open at any given time in a *Workbook*. These are features of Excel and can only be used if you're using a format that supports those like `xls` or `xlsx` (Excel's native formats), or something comparable.

CSV is just a clear text file that has an assumed structure. It has no native support for formatting or metadata (other than typical file system stuff). Lacking that support for metadata, there's no way to tell Excel what the sheet should be named, so it gets the default. In fact, if you try and save an Excel document as a CSV file with multiple sheets, Excel (2016) will only save the active sheet.

To get the level of control you want, you'll need ot use a library that's meant to deal with `xlsx` files, but that'll add a considerable level of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is just a text file, not a spreadsheet. If you open a CSV file in NotePad, you will see that it's just data, separated by the Windows List Separator character - in many countries the comma acts as separator, hence the abbreviation CVS = Comma Separated Values.

A CSV file stores no information at all on formatting, formulas, sheets etc. - just values. Also by virtue of it's structure a CSV file is a single sheet of data which Excel recognizes; one cannot have a multiple sheet CSV.

My suggestion is to use PhpSpreadsheet to create Excel file which can store Sheet name and other related information.

[PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a really primitive format and doesn't allow you to specify the sheet name because the very concept of sheets is totally foreign to it.

You'll need to generate an `.xls` or `.xlsx` file to name sheets. This requires a different library.